# CSS: auto-size a html "div" so width is set by the container and the height is automatically set to maintains aspect ratio of the background image

Tags: css, background-image, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to create a picture frame around an image.  I am trying to use css "Border-image". I would also like to have both a inner and outer shadow for the picture frame. I'm trying to use box-shadow to apply the frame shadows.

From what I have read online for the box-shadow to work (at least one of the ways that works best for me) is to set the image to the "background-image" for the .

Currently the only way I have been able to get the automatic resizing of  to work is  image was to set the background of the "div" to the image and also add an , containing the same image, within the . so I specify the image twice. This has to do with an issue with the box-shadow inner shadow.

Then within the css I set the  to "width: auto" and the  "width: 80wv) (100vw -(2 * border (4vw) + margin (1vw)). Then I calculate the height of the  "height: calc(80vw * (9 /16));" and the height of the background "background-size: 80vw calc(80vw * (9 /16));".

I would like the css section for the  to be more generic. In this example I know the image aspect ratio, and I can calculate it, but I'm going to have a lot more images and I don't want to create a section for every image aspect ratio. Please help.

Here is the sample HTML code I have been working on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sea and Spice</title>
    </head>
        <div class="WovenBamboo" style="background-image:url('All_Eastern_Food_Wood_Background_Expanded_L1_V6.1.jpg');" >
            <img class="UHD" src="All_Eastern_Food_Wood_Background_Expanded_L1_V6.1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="WovenBamboo" style="background-image:url('All_Breakfast_Food_UHD_L1_V12.0.jpg');" >
            <img class="UHD" src="All_Breakfast_Food_UHD_L1_V12.0.jpg" />
        </div>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the css:

```
.WovenBamboo {
    width: 80vw;
    height: calc(80vw * (9 /16));
    border: 4vw solid orange;
    margin: 1vw;
    padding: 0px;


    border-image-source: url("../pictures/Woven_Bamboo_Picture_Frame/Woven_Bamboo_Picture_Frame_Boarder_500x500_8bit_V4.0.png");
    border-image-slice: 40% 40% 40% 40% fill;
    border-image-repeat: repeat;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px #000,inset 0px 0px 5px 5px #000;

    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:80vw calc(80vw * (9 /16));
}

.UHD {
    width: auto !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I would like to make the WovenBamboo section more generic and not be fixed to a specific aspect ratio. I would prefer no having to calculate the height based on a fixed aspect ratio. I would prefer to assign an image to the  and have the sizing be automatic based on the with of the  (like 80% or 80vw or 600px). thanks again for any help you can provide.

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.